# I want to let the data to be shown on the edittext

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to let the data to be shown on the edittext first. How can I do it? I've already passed the data to the modify page, and I want to let the data first show on the edittext, then let the user change the title if the user needs to change.

Here are my modify page code:

```
public class MeTodolistModify extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String student_id,student_name,title,input;
    private EditText addtext;
    private Button change;
    private int position;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_me_todolist_modify);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        title = bundle.getString("title");
        position = bundle.getInt("position");
        student_id = bundle.getString("student_id");
        student_name = bundle.getString("student_name");
        createDetail();
    }

    private void createDetail(){

        final FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("Student").child(student_id).child("event");

        Log.e("MOD",String.valueOf(position));

        Log.e("MOD2",title);

        change = findViewById(R.id.change);

        change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText addtext = findViewById(R.id.addtext);
                input = addtext.getText().toString();
                ref.child(Integer.toString(position)).setValue(input);

                Intent intent;
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.change:
                        intent = new Intent(MeTodolistModify.this, MeTodolist.class);
                        intent.putExtra("student_id", student_id );
                        intent.putExtra("student_name",student_name);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

The update code for modify page:

```
 public class MeTodolistModify extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String student_id,student_name,title,input;
    private EditText addtext;
    private Button change;
    private int position;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_me_todolist_modify);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        title = bundle.getString("title");
        position = bundle.getInt("position");
        student_id = bundle.getString("student_id");
        student_name = bundle.getString("student_name");
        createDetail();
    }

    private void createDetail(){

        final FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("Student").child(student_id).child("event");

        Log.e("MOD",String.valueOf(position));

        Log.e("MOD2",title);

        change = findViewById(R.id.change);

        change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText addtext = findViewById(R.id.addtext);
                addtext.setText(title);
                input = addtext.getText().toString();
                ref.child(Integer.toString(position)).setValue(input);

                Intent intent;
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.change:
                        intent = new Intent(MeTodolistModify.this, MeTodolist.class);
                        intent.putExtra("student_id", student_id );
                        intent.putExtra("student_name",student_name);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after getting title from bundle

```
title = bundle.getString("title");
```

set `title` to `EditText`

```
addtext.setText(title)
```

later user can change if he wants

Comment: I've try it. But It doesn't shown on the `edittext`, and when I press the change button, it will automatically erase the user's change and change in to the data that I've just pass to here, and store back to the database.

Comment: `Log.e("MOD2",title);` is this printing the text you want for `edittext` , Can you update code after setting title to edittext

Comment: Yes, I use `Log.e("MOD2",title);` to check if I am successfully pass the title to this modify page. The update code is shown on the top.

Comment: I´ve set it in the `change.setOnClickListener` . I've updated in my question the last one.

Comment: You are setting then going to another activity you cant see the text even if you set . But why are you adding text in OnClickListener ? . If you set text outside OnClickListener you can see text changing in edittext

Comment: So what should I do ? My object is to let the User change the word they type and when I click the button, it will store the data and then jump back to the previous page.

Comment: Just call setText() outside of onClickListener . It will set text in edittext, now user can change as he wants, it will solve all your problems .if he clicks on change button you will get updated text from edittext and save it (which you already doing)

Comment: I put `setText()`outside of the onClickListener. and it says "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference"

Comment: come on . you have to initialize first and then setText(). You should call this method :  `EditText addtext = findViewById(R.id.addtext);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically set data to `EditText`

`addtext.setText("Some text");`